# useState not updating rendered values after getting document snapshots

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am having a problem assigning data to `useState` by fetching data using reference type value from firebase.

```
const [preOil, setPreOil] = useState([]);
const [oilChange, setOilChange] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
getDocs(query(collection(db, "oil"), orderBy("timestamp"))).then(
  (snapshot) => {
    setPreOil(
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }))
    );
  }
);
}, []);


useEffect(() => {
  let current = preOil.length > 0 ? [...preOil] : [];

  current.map((_oil, i) => {
    getDoc(_oil.oilReference).then((oilRef) => {
      current[i].oilReference = oilRef.data();
    });
  });

  setOilChange(current);
}, [preOil]);
```

**In the first `useEffect`, the data is fetched successfully in this form,**

```
preOil = {
        id:"RxbAOAIs8d3kGOHNskJ4",
        oilReference: Ta {converter: null, _key: ut, type: 'document', firestore: Na},
        customerName: "USAMA",
}
```

In the second `useEffect` based on `[preOil]`, I need to reassign the `oilReference` with the data fetched from firestorm through its reference(`oilReference`), The data is successfully fetched from the database and assigned to `current` but **The main problem is when I set to state `setOilChange(current)` it updates my `oilChange` state when I inspect in inspect tools in chrome but in JSX the changes don't reflect**

- I am updating the state in `useEffect`
- I am having desired data assigned in a local variable and assign that variable to the state

**Then What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `useEffect()`, more specifically, in

```js
current.map((_oil, i) => {
  getDoc(_oil.oilReference).then((oilRef) => {
    current[i].oilReference = oilRef.data();
  });
});
setOilChange(current);
```

You are mutating the content of the `current` variable. This mutation, because it is async, will happen *after* the `setOilChange` call. Such mutation will thus not trigger a re-render.

What you need is to instead first wait for all the docs to be loaded and only after that set the state. Example:

```js
const _docs = current.map((_oil, i) => {
  return getDoc(_oil.oilReference).then((oilRef) => { // changed here
    return {                                          // changed here
      ...current[i],                                  // changed here
      oilReference: oilRef.data()                     // changed here
    }                                                 // changed here
  });                                                 // changed here
});

Promise.all(_docs).then(() => {
  setOilChange(_docs);
});
```

Also notice I didn't mutate `current`, rather I returned a new object. This is not mandatory but just a best practice overall.

Comment: This is helpful and you need to update the code,
Promise.all(docs).then((_docs) => {
  setOilChange(_docs);
});